# Chrome Extension to tag and view tagged whatsapp chats

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, whatsapp

I'm trying to build a chrome extension that could filter my whatsapp chats based on tags I would add on them. To do this, I was planning to create a map of the chat elements in the chat list and based on the tags selected I would show the respective chats.

Following are some approaches I tried:

## Approach 1

scroll over the chat list in the DOM and clone the chat nodes, store a mapping of using the pixel offset in the `transform: translateY(72px)` style attribute

```html
<div class="lhggkp7q ln8gz9je rx9719la" role="listitem" style="z-index: 614; transition: none 0s ease 0s; height: 72px; transform: translateY(216px);"><div class="g0rxnol2">
```

I'd end up with a map like

```js
[
    0: <node with pixel offset 0>,
    72: <node with pixel offset 72>,
    ...
]
```

Problem

- nodes are cloned and the map is created successfully. I can add the nodes back to the DOM as I would want but the clicks on the cloned nodes do not work. Looks like the event listeners of the original node are not working on the cloned nodes.

From what I can see, the chat list is a virtual list and the nodes are updated on the fly as you scroll. So, all the nodes are not available in the DOM and hence cannot be manipulated.

The event listeners of these nodes are probably on the parent element `div #app` and the event listeners are not triggered on the cloned nodes.

I added a `click` and `pointerdown` event listener on the `#app` element with useCapture to check if the event listeners are triggered from there when we click on chats and they do. So, the event listeners are on the parent element and not on the nodes themselves.

## Approach 2

I move the nodes into a hidden div and then move them back into the chat list when needed.

The problem here is that scrolling the chat list continues to update the moved nodes in the hidden list and the moved nodes get updated so moving them is useless.

I feel approach 1 was doing a good job but I'm not sure how to get the event listeners to work on the cloned nodes. I tried using `cloneNode(true)`, `clone(true)`, `clone(true, true)` but none of them seem to work (probably because the event listeners are on the parent element and not on the node itself).
I assume the event listeners are not delegated to the child nodes and hence the cloned nodes do not work.

How can I get the event listeners to work on the cloned nodes? Or is there a better way to do this?

Reference:

I found a somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77609850/chrome-extension-for-sending-whatsapp-messages-with-name) but this is using mutation observer to manipulate the sent text on the LHS chat interface but I don't see how this can be used to manipulate the RHS chat interface.

There are existing extensions which do override and control the interface as needed so I'm sure this is possible but I'm not sure how to do it.
E.g. [WAPlus](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/waplus-crm-best-crm-for-w/jmjcgjmipjiklbnfbdclkdikplgajhgc?pli=1)

Comment: Add `style="display:none!important"` on the elements. P.S. Event listeners of an element aren't preserved by cloneNode. If the element is not present in the actually presented DOM then it won't receive any events either.

Comment: did you mean adding the style to the chat elements? I did but that doesn't help. It only hides the elements but they're still linked to whatever event listener is linked to them and the virtual list still gets updated. How are you suggesting I would be able to manipulate them this way? Not sure I follow

and yes, cloneNode doesn't preserve event listeners and I've tried jquery's clone as well which does. However, in this case, the event listeners are on a parent #app element and not on the chat elements.

Comment: Sounds like there's no robust method to do it via DOM. Try hacking into the app's code by reverse-engineering its code and spoofing/intercepting its methods in [page context](/a/9517879).