# Not able to change `textContent` of WhatsApp Web from Extension's Content Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, whatsapp

EDIT:

I just noticed that this code works but the website is so quick that when the textContent is assigned 'Changed' it changes it back to what I was typing and that was so quick I was not able to figure it out that if it even changed, but because of some lag I was able to see the transition from "Changed" to what I was typing

---

In my chrome extension I'm trying to change the dom of whatsapp web
I'm taking the chat element and trying to change the content of it but I'm unable to do it
this is my code

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const spanEl = target.querySelector('span[data-lexical-text="true"]');
        console.log(spanEl, spanEl.textContent);
        spanEl.textContent = 'Changed';
        });
    });
});
```

But the above code does not reflect any change while with the same code I'm able to change the Text Content of other elements, the chat box element's text content does not change.

The HTML element of WhatsApp Web

```html
<div class="to2l77zo gfz4du6o ag5g9lrv bze30y65 kao4egtt" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" spellcheck="true" title="Type a message" tabindex="10" data-tab="10" data-lexical-editor="true" style="max-height: 7.35em; min-height: 1.47em; user-select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word;">
  <p class="selectable-text copyable-text iq0m558w g0rxnol2" dir="ltr" style="text-indent: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <span class="selectable-text copyable-text" data-lexical-text="true">as</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Comment: @Shivansh, as you've already found out WA keeps updating the page to reflect the internal state.
Take a look at this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77609850/chrome-extension-for-sending-whatsapp-messages-with-name

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better selector matching your HTML

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.querySelector("[contenteditable=true]").addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    const spanEl = event.target.querySelector('span[data-lexical-text="true"]');
    spanEl.textContent = 'Changed';
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="to2l77zo gfz4du6o ag5g9lrv bze30y65 kao4egtt" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" spellcheck="true" title="Type a message" tabindex="10" data-tab="10" data-lexical-editor="true" style="max-height: 7.35em; min-height: 1.47em; user-select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; word-break: break-word;">
  <p class="selectable-text copyable-text iq0m558w g0rxnol2" dir="ltr" style="text-indent: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <span class="selectable-text copyable-text" data-lexical-text="true">as</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for answering, actually the element I'm on which is target is the chat box element on which I'm typing, I'm also console logging the text content of the target and it does gives me what I'm typing so I'm sure that the target element is correct, but assigning new text content to this element does not work except other elements I'm able to change their text content easily

Comment: See my updated script

Comment: The assignment of new textContent does not work

```js
spanEl.textContent = 'Changed';
```

Comment: I just noticed that this code works but the website is so quick that when the textContent is assigned 'Changed' it changes it back to what I was typing and that was so quick I was not able to figure it out that if it even changed, but because of some lag I was able to see the trasition from "Changed" to what I was typing